# ssh: heroku: no address associated with name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails by using the [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org). 
Every time I type the command `git push heroku master`, I get the following error message:

```
ssh: heroku: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a remote called `heroku` configured? Try `git remote -v` to see your remotes.

Comment: Yes, I did. Here's what happens:
`heroku git@heroku:.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku:.git (push)
origin http://github.com/<username>/first_app.git (fetch)
origin http://github.com/<username>/first_app.git (push)`
I don't even know what a "remote" would be, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Your `heroku` remote isn't configured properly. It should look something like

```
git@heroku.com:something-weird-1234.git (fetch)
git@heroku.com:something-weird-1234.git (push)
```

Log into Heroku and see what your App is called. Then update your configuration like so:

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:<app-name-copied-from-heroku>
git remote set-url --push heroku git@heroku.com:<app-name-copied-from-heroku>
```

Comment: Thank you, it really worked. But there was another problem: 
`Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Ra/.ssh/id_rsa':
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 73, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (56/56), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 15.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)


 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:mighty-mountain-9717.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:mighty-mountain-9717.git'`